# Product page in BO won't load because of huge numbe of combiations

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am wondering if there is any way like script / module / override for a prestashop 1.7 to display product combinations in othere tab / window. We have products that client assigned a lot of combinations, like ~25 000. Because of that when we try to enter product edit in BO, we are getting 500 error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cakTx.png)

I found a method called `formAction` causing this situatio in Admin/ProductController

I tried to create a pagination but for me it is to complicated

Comment: Your Q is not about code. you need to improve your db structure based on your queries and also increase your server resources.